# Incorrect URL in browser using JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm creating login form using JSF 2.0. Below is the detailed description.

When I run the form, I get the login.xhtml

Once I get successfully logged in, I get page as temp1.xhtml and when I click the link (that I have created on temp1.xhtml page) I get temp2.xhtml page.

All is working perfectly... but the problem of URL which is described below...

When I successfully logged in, the browser still shows URL as login.xhtml instead if temp1.xhtml

when I click on the link that is on temp1.xhtml, I get temp2.xhtml page but the URL says temp1.xhtml instead of temp2.xhtml

Could any one help me to show the correct URL as I have to filter these pages and as URL is INCORRECT my filter is useless...

***Please note that I am not using configuration file for directing the pages...***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to add:

`?faces-redirect=true` in the end of the view that you are directing.

e.g:

```
return "mypage?faces-redirect=true"
```

Comment: in StackOverFlow, those who answer retrieve 15 points if the one who asked marked the answer as correct. Next to my answer, on the left side, you will see a V. please click on it to mark it green - and mark my answer as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

you can also directly use it in the .xhtml files for example on page temp1.xhtml page in link use action="temp2?faces-redirect=true"

Comment: Yes, it is same as what Odelya mentioned above. And I am doing same for link too and it is working perfectly....

Still thanks for your response too :)

Comment: what i meant was u can do it either ways 1)By returning the .xhtml from your bean class or 2) by directly using it in action on your link.

Comment: However this way you won't be able to invoke a business action (such as actually logging in the user).